# How to keep UV set position while moving an object?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I would like to keep a UVset position in the world coordinates while moving my object.

So the texture have to stay in place in the world while the model moves.

How do I make this?

Thank you
Chris

Comment: How does your object or texture look like? is it a simple plane? I may have a solution by you must give some details

Answer (score 4):

You can map your texture using another object. If you move the one with the material, the texture will stay still. If you move the 2nd object, the texture will move.
[image: mapping]